# What's the connection's identifier when creating a TCP server?

Tags: javascript, tcp, node.js, connection

I am using node.js to create a TCP server and each connection would be persistent. Known that node.js is single process, how to tell apart each connection? Is there something like connection ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create one yourself

```
var net = require('net');

var connects_count = 0;

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.connectionId = connects_count;
  connects_count++;
  socket.write("Echo server\r\n");
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just noticed that socket has a native property 'fd', and can this file descriptor be used for unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

`socket.remoteAddress`?

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/net.html#net.Socket